# Xcode: instantiating a view controller with custom variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, instantiation

So I want to instantiate a view controller from storyboard and change its static variables.

This is "vc1" - the view controller to be instantiated:

```
import UIKit

class vc1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_title: UILabel!
    
    static var title = "initial value"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lbl_title.text = vc1.title
    }
}
```

And this is my root vc.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn_go: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func btn_gogogo(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1") as! vc1
        
        vc.title = "bla"

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here I'm trying to change the static variable of the view controller that I just instantiated,
with no effect. The variable ( in my case 'title' ) is always stuck to its initial value.

What is the problem here?

Best

Mark

Comment: Why are you choosing to have `title` be `static`?

Comment: to be able to access it from the root vc !?

Comment: In the code you've shared, there's no reason for it to be `static`

Comment: you are right... understood :-)
but my problem still remains unchanged

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the line where you set the title inside of a “DispatchQueue.main.async”?

Comment: just did... no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to override the view controller's `title` property. Instead, create your own:

```
class vc1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_title: UILabel!
    
    var myTitle = "initial value"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        lbl_title.text = myTitle
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var btn_go: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func btn_gogogo(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1") as! vc1
        
        vc.myTitle = "bla"
        
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```